# Unidentified sci fi book that is referenced in Earthweb by Marc Stiegler

Tags: story-identification, books

There is a book in Marc Stiegler's *Earthweb* (1999) but only a description of the book cover is given.

[Extract](https://books.google.gr/books?id=fPhIDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT64&lpg=PT64&dq=As%20a%20child,%20her%20favorite%20painting%20had%20been%20a%20picture%20of%20a%20flying%20battleship,%20dashing%20fiercely%20across%20a%20field%20of%20fire%20where%20every%20color%20of%20the%20rainbow%20danced%20in%20a%20frenzy%20of%20light.%20The%20painting%20was%20the%20original%20cover%20art%20for%20an%20early%20SF%20book%20about%20the%20coming&source=bl&ots=R0Rp6UMkhR&sig=ACfU3U1kGVMVUjsOI7cXzXLMh9L9cA7DgA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0-trhkI3nAhWK-6QKHby8Cf0Q6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=As%20a%20child%2C%20her%20favorite%20painting%20had%20been%20a%20picture%20of%20a%20flying%20battleship%2C%20dashing%20fiercely%20across%20a%20field%20of%20fire%20where%20every%20color%20of%20the%20rainbow%20danced%20in%20a%20frenzy%20of%20light.%20The%20painting%20was%20the%20original%20cover%20art%20for%20an%20early%20SF%20book%20about%20the%20coming&f=false) from *Earthweb*:

> The two walls with neither screens nor windows held a careful selection of pre-Crash artwork. As a child, her favorite painting had been a picture of a flying battleship, dashing fiercely across a field of fire where every color of the rainbow danced in a frenzy of light. The painting was the original cover art for an early SF book about the coming age of global networking. She had read the book once, as a child, and had received a small shock that prepared her well for a future of Web literature. The book had not contained a single word about flying battleships. She liked the painting nonetheless.

Comment: SF publishers are strange creatures; they sometimes slap on whatever cover art they already have the rights to rather than commission an artist to create something new. My guess is that this is just a reference to this common practice. Also notice that _Earthweb_ itself has flying battleships in it.

Comment: I've dropped Marc Stiegler a quick twit. Hopefully he'll take the time to respond

Comment: @Valorum doesn't seem very active in the medium - his last tweet is from Dec 2017

Comment: @desertnaut - Sure, but it's always worth a prod. I'll try his email in a day or two if he hasn't come back to me

Comment: At the end of the book is a link that purports to explain details from the book. Sadly this is now (over 20 years later) a dead link.   http://www.the-earthweb.com

Comment: @dannymcg wayback machine! Site had moved to http://www.skyhunter.com/earthweb/index.html but I saw no info on the described book.